# TTTAttributedLabel add action to truncation ("Read more" text)

Tags: ios, tttattributedlabel

I can show "... Read more" in UILabel using TTTAttributedLabel.

```
[lblContent setAttributedTruncationToken:str];
```

But I need to trigger another action when user tap on that text. I try to modify inside TTTAttributedLabel and it is not okay. How shall I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215965/tttattributedlabel-delegate-didselectlinkwithurl-is-not-getting-called-in-iphone

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: no. look like i need to modify deeply. Need to find last line and override the part where it add read more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
label.attributedTruncationToken = NSAttributedString(string: "...Read more", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : label.font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor()])
```